# Adding column to CP entries without writing plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel

Is there a way to add a column to the control panel display of entries? I would strongly prefer to not write a plug-in for this. The contents in the column would be nothing more than a button that links to a URL containing the UID of the entry. Note, I am not using the Commerce plug-in here.

If I have to write a plug-in, what would be the simplest scaffold to use?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple-ish way you could do this is by using the [pre-parse field](https://plugins.craftcms.com/preparse-field) to parse `{{ entry.uid }}`.

This will then give you an extra column with the unique ID. You can then use [Control panel JS](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-js) to change that into a link/create a button. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Craft.elementIndex.on('updateElements ', function(data){
        if (data.target.$source.data('handle') == 'your-section-handle') {
            $('td[data-attr=field:your-field-id]').each(function(){
                <!-- JS code to change uid into link -->
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Replacing `your-section-handle` and `your-field-id`.

Comment: Of course, there already is a UID column – so you could just use that instead of Pre-parse.

Comment: Thanks, dmatthams. If I put the correct section handle and field ID in place, with no extra code, should this run without issue? I decided to just target the entry ID field (id), because I can build my button from that.

`$(document).ready(function() {
  Craft.elementIndex.on('updateElements ', function(data){
      if (data.target.$source.data('handle') == 'test') {
          $('td[data-attr=field:id]').each(function(){
              //
          });
      }
  });
});`